# Bootstrap two column layout image and text responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap how can i split the column for the image and text to be responsive just like the image below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMvkH.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a page that looks like the image in your post. I would do something like this in bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <Image scr="">
            <Image scr="">
            <Image scr="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want the column sizes to respond to the screen size simply add a class for that size.  For example if you want a column to take up the full width of the screen on small screens but only half on medium to large you could do

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" >...</div>
```

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly

Comment: No problem glad to help

Comment: @ashokkumarn12 If someones answer completely works for you, you should click the check mark on left side to accept it. You can accept only one answer, so choose the best one.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/6p1qmvst/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="images">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<style>
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50vw 50vw;
    grid-gap: 0;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid;
}

.box+.box {
    border-left: 0;
}

.images {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.image {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center
}

img {
    border: 1px solid;
}
</style>
```